# How to check if TextBox's cursor is blinking

Tags: c#, uwp

This is for an UWP app. I only found a way to check if TextBox is unfocused but it's not working. I want to check if the TextBox has a blinking cursor so you can type in it versus when the focus is lost (no blinking cursor).

```
    if (textBoxCool.FocusState == FocusState.Unfocused)
    {
        // Do something
    }
    else
    { 
        // Do something else
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

TextBox has **LostFocus** and **GettingFocus** event.When TextBox's cursor blinking,it will trigger GettingFocus event and when no blinking cursor,it will trigger LostFoucs event.

.xaml:

```
<TextBox  x:Name="textBoxCool" Width="200" LostFocus="TextBox_LostFocus" GettingFocus="TextBox_GettingFocus"></TextBox>
```

.cs

```
private void TextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {​
            //Do something
        }​
​
private void TextBox_GettingFocus(UIElement sender, GettingFocusEventArgs args)​
        {​
            //Do something else
        }
```

Comment: LostFocus and GettingFocus are child of `Windows.UI.Xaml`, are not ? `Windows.UI.Xaml` is `Nuget` Package

Comment: Can you describe why you didn't achieve the desired effect using this method?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using events for this to work properly. You don't want to use a conditional like that because then you'll still need an event to trigger it later. There's an event called `"OnPointerEntered"` and another `"OnPointerExited"` which you can use in lieu of your `if-else` statement.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.onpointerentered

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.onpointerexited

Focus returns a bool value of `true` if focus was set to the control or already on the control whereas `false` if the control `IS NOT FOCUSABLE`. This means you can't use it inside a conditional like that unless you set the `textBoxCool` to un-focusable somewhere else in code.

Comment: I think that's not gonna work for me because after the mouse pointer hovers on the TextBox and I click it to show the blinking line cursor, then I'll have to move the mouse pointer away to click a button.

Comment: @EsAMe what exactly are you attempting to accomplish by detecting if the cursor is blinking?